# Want to store email id in bot framework and pass it as variable in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

i am working on bot framework, i want to bot should ask a question i.e "Please enter your email id ?" from messagecontroller.cs file and when user enter the email id as a reply then it should store in a variable and that variable can pass. 
i am new to c# and bot framework.

THe question should be written in the conversationUpadate type.

Answer (score 0):

You can add global variables in your dialog and store the values there, or manage the conversational state through the Bot Builder as stated in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)